Android drawable array from JSON
In JSON file I have data and also drawables as a String:
{"title": "title1","thumb": "R.drawable.image1"},{"title": "title2","thumb": "R.drawable.image2"}

I am parsing it like
JSONObject obj = myjArry.getJSONObject(i);
String thumb = obj.getString("thumb");

and then I try to assign the drawable to ImageView in my adapter:
 int tm = Integer.parseInt(actorList.get(position).getThumb());
 holder.thumb.setImageResource(tm);

The problem is, I can't convert a text String to int as it is not a number, but setImageResource requires integer.
Now I have this error:
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "R.drawable.image1"

PS: if possible without getIdentifier(), as this is not encouraged to use.

"if possible without getIdentifier(), as this is not encouraged to use." - probably not possible, that's the whole point of that method: to get the Int resource by it's name.

Create a map to store the mappings between string identifiers and resource IDs;
Map<String, Integer> thumbMap = new HashMap<>();

@Maveňツ  might be good solution, but it's unreliable and error-prone. For example it will fail for if you have  the actual field name will be string_name. But the bigger issue it will fail in production (release build) if resource/code shrinking is enabled (and Google encourages to enable it). Instead of this just mapping string names to integer ids is better I think. But thank you for the alternative

You need to use Resources#getIdentifier method to get an id using a resource name like:
String name = actorList.get(position).getThumb();

Resources res = context.getResources();
int resId = res.getIdentifier(name, "drawable", context.getPackageName());

holder.thumb.setImageResource(resId);


yes, thank you I did it this way, however getIdentifier is discouraged according the Lint in Android Studio, I wanted to avoid it. I know it is not an error, just a suggestion, but still, if there is no other solution. Will check also the Mapping solution.
